# Is this useEffect() unecessarily expensive?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is a very simple version of my code:

```
const MyComponent = (props)=>{
    const [randVar, setRandVar] = useState(null);
    const randomFunction = ()=>{
           console.log(randVar, props);
    };
    useCustomHook = ()=>{
       useEffect(()=>{
           document.addEventListener('keydown', randomFunction);

            return ()=>{
                document.removeEventListener('keydown', randomFunction);
            }
       }, [props, randVar]);
    }

    useCustomHook();

    ...
};
```

I want randomFunction to log accurate values for randVar and props (i.e. logs update when those variables change values), but I'm concerned that adding an event listener and then dismounting it every time they change is really inefficient.

Is there another way to get randomFunction to log updated values without adding props and randVar as dependencies in useEffect?

Answer (score 2):

A few things, your `useEffect` does not need to be in that custom hook at all... It should probably look like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props)=>{
    const [randVar, setRandVar] = useState(null);
    const randomFunction = useCallback(()=>{
           console.log(randVar, props);
    }, [props, randVar]);

   useEffect(()=>{
       document.addEventListener('keydown', randomFunction);

        return ()=>{
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', randomFunction);
        }
   }, [randomFunction]);

    ...
};
```

`useCallback` will keep your function from being redefined on every render, and is the correct dependency for that `useEffect` as well. The only thing bad about the performance ehre is that you are logging `props` so it needs to be in the dependency array of the `useCallback` and since it is an object that may get redefined a lot, it will cause your `useCallback` to get redefined on nearly every render, which will then cause your `useEffect` to be fired on nearly every render.

My only suggestion there would be to separate your logging of props from where you log changes to `randVar`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `randVar` as a dependency and if you had ESLint, it would tell you the same since you never acutally reference `randVar` in the effect.

If you don't want the function to get rebuilt over and over, you need to either memoize it or `useRef`.  Unfortunately, once it's a ref it's not reactive.  Maybe I'm overthinking this, but you could have a ref that you update in an effect with the new value and print out the value of that ref in the callback you pass to `randFunction`.  See my example below.

I don't like how I did this, but it doesn't remake the function.  I'm trying to think how I could do it better, but I think this works how you want.

```js
const {
  useRef,
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const useCustomHook = (fn) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", fn);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", fn);
    };
  }, [fn]);
};

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [randVar, setRandVar] = useState("");
  const randVarRef = useRef("");

  useEffect(() => {
    randVarRef.current = randVar;
  }, [randVar]);

  const randFn = useRef(() => {
    console.log(randVarRef.current);
  });

  useCustomHook(randFn.current);

  return React.createElement("input", {
    type: "text",
    value: randVar,
    onChange: e => {
      setRandVar(e.target.value);
    }
  });
};

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyComponent),
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```